# whatsapp date and time inaccurate

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-635

Why are they saying whatsapp date n time not correct on my Lumia 635. The date and time is correct but they saying is not correct..
[image]

Comment: What region does your phone think it's in? How close to known good time source (such as the hourly news on the radio) is the phone?